# Irregular CSS corners?

Tags: css

Have a client request for irregular corners in CSS. Is that even a thing? So far I had experimented with CSS triangles ( http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ ) but no bueno.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/irreg.png

Thinking I'll probably have to do it with images sadly... unless y'alls know of any way to pull it off.

The main parameters: Needs to be at least flexible in height, preferably flexible in width too, but not required. Current solution: Top capper that extends potentially above the box enough to make the corner effect work on the secondary box... with the lower descender pieces right absolutely aligned pushing below.

My closest attempt so far (uses image for top): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4031469/fs.html

Comment: You could try to work around this using css, but it's probably going to be convoluted and hard to maintain, so I'd suggest stick to images.

Comment: Yes, something like this would usually be achieved with background-images.

Comment: What browsers are you trying to target?

Comment: I'm actually only targeting chrome... it's going to be used as an on-air product for a TV show you might watch. :)

Comment: Chrome only? you could play with a SVG-heavy layout or a Canvas. Not sure if that would be any *quicker*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Under CSS3, as far as I've researched, the particulars of this look make it not yet possible.</strike>

This look has a subtle gradient and inner glow, which we've accomplished using an `inset` box shadow... that seems to not work with the prior css triangle effects.

CSS Masks look like they might be able to assist in many circumstances, but in circumstances requiring `box-shadow: inset`, images are the only way to go.

Today I got this working using the -webkit-clip-path property, which has varying browser support.

```
.entry{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 90% 0%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;

}

body{
  background-color: green; 
}
```

http://codepen.io/randallb/pen/tmlAH

Answer (score 3):

Stealing from http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/

[image: screen snip from jsfiddle in chrome]

<strike>http://jsfiddle.net/aBYHX/</strike>

**EDIT :-** Second attempt. Simpler, less css and on the same side as your example pic. 
   ​
http://jsfiddle.net/aBYHX/1/

```
<div class="content">
    <p class="triangle-isosceles">This only needs one HTML element.</p>
    <p class="irregular-corner"> ---- </p>
</div>​
```

Css:

```
.content
{
    padding: 15px;
}
.triangle-isosceles, .irregular-corner 
{
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
    margin:1em 0 3em;
    color:#000;
    background:#f3961c;
}

.triangle-isosceles:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    border-width: 25px 50px 0 0; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent white;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; 
}


.irregular-corner:before
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top: -25px; 
    right: 0px; 
    border-width: 25px 50px 0 0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent #f3961c;
    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; 
}
​
```

Comment: @EzequielMuns It relies on having a white background though. This is so a section can be cut out.

Comment: What gradients? I thought we were doing corners?

Comment: Gradients on the corners. If you reference the original image, you'll note that the corner things have gradients in them... so you can't do gradients on css borders.

Comment: @RandallB you can do [gradients on css borders](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) but I don't know much about them. I have a third approach that gets you a little closer: http://jsfiddle.net/aBYHX/7/

Answer (score 0):

Nora Brown wrote a lovely article on the [CSS3 border-image property](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/).  It's worth a quick read...

If you're worried about cross-browser support (and you should be), then offer a graceful fallback.  Perhaps just having a border with no "crazy corners" would do as a fallback situation, perhaps not.

This method isn't cross-browser, but some find it nice to be "[progressive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLsAim3FQr8)".